# Prime Factors function crashes console

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why this code is crashing my console:

```
var isPrime = function(n) {
    for (i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
            break
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
};
var primeFactors = function(n) {
    factorsArray = [];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            if (i % n === 0) {
                factorsArray.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return factorsArray
}
```

When I run the "isPrime" function by itself, it runs great.  However, the primeFactors function (for any value greater than 3) will crash the console.  I don't see how it could be an infinite loop.  May not be the most efficient solution to the problem, but it should still work I think......

Comment: Why do you think your `isPrime` works? It simply doesn't.

Comment: Why do you say my isPrime function doesn't work?  I'll give you that it doesn't work for any values less than 3 (returns none)(which I have since added in handling for that), and does not handle negative integers (I haven't looked up how to do absolute value in JS yet), but when you run the function, it works. If n is prime, it returns true.  If n is not prime, it returns false.  I just ran this code in my console and it works just fine.

Comment: So for example if you pass `9` to it, it will return `true`, which is wrong. This is becuz both your `if` and `else` parts are returning immediately; your `for` loop never runs more than once.

Comment: can someone please help me understand or direct me to a resource to explain why this isPrime function doesn't work?  It seems to work for every integer greater than 3 except 9.  9 is the only value of n that returns a "false positive".  Pardon the newbness...

Comment: That is not the case. It won't work for 15, 25, 27, 33 and many many more numbers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least four issues:

1) You need to use `var` in front of both your uses of `i` because they are implicit globals and are stomping on each other.  So, one `for` loop messes up the other `for` loop.

2) You also need to change:

```
if (i % n === 0)
```

to

```
if (n % i === 0)
```

3) You need to let `isPrime()` run all the iterations and only return true if all the iterations have succeeded.

4) You shouldn't be testing `0` and `1` as factors.

You can see this fixed version work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8wgvypb6/:

```
var isPrime = function(n) {
    for (var i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if (n % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

var primeFactors = function(n) {
    var factorsArray = [];
    for (var i=2; i<n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            if (n % i === 0) {
                factorsArray.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return factorsArray;
}
```

There are many, many ways to make this much, much more efficient, but I just corrected the errors in your particular approach to make it work.

Comment: so does a return statement immediately make you exit a function? I thought the function would run to completion after iterating through all the values and it would return the last thing you told it to return.

Comment: @SeanIvins - a `return` statement returns immediately.  You don't want to execute a `return` until the function is done and you have the final value you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. Fixed a few drastic errors and introduced some optimizations. Note that I have modified the code by hand, so there may be some syntax issues:

```
var isPrime = function (n) {
    if (n == 2) return true;           //2 is prime
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;      //other even numbers are not prime

    //try division upto the square-root of the given number. If we don't find
    //a divisor, the number is prime.
    for (var i = 3; i <= Math.ceil( Math.sqrt(n)) + 1; i+=2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;       
};

var primeFactors = function (n) {
    factorsArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i) && (n % i == 0)) {
            factorsArray.push(i);
            n /= i;
            i--; //nullify the effect of next for iteration (becuz a composite can 
                 //have one prime factor multiple times; e.g. 24 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 3
        }
    }
    return factorsArray
}
```

Comment: `i % n == 0` is never going to do what you want it to because `i` is always less than `n`.  This was one of the OP's main errors.

Comment: @jfriend00: thanks. fixed. OP's biggest problem was his `isPrime()` function, which was effectively doing nothing.

Comment: jfriend00, not sure what I was thinking with the `i % n`.  I changed it to `n % i == 0` which checks if it is a factor. After this fix, the code still inifinite loops, though....

Comment: @SeanIvins - yes, because there are two other problems in your code.  I've listed all three issues in my answer and have a working demo of the fixed code.

Comment: @dotNET I don't understand why your isPrime doesn't return true every time.  I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how control flow works.  I would think that every time the isPrime function runs, the last line of code it would run no matter what the value would be the `return true;`

Comment: @SeanIvins: Try to digest this: In languages like C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, VB, VB.NET and many more, when `return` is encountered, code **immediately** returns to the calling function, without executing any other lines in the body of that function. There are some exceptions to this rule, but I'll skip those for now. So remember that `return` actually asks the control flow to *return* to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Your isPrime function will only make one iteration of the loop this is because you have a return statement in both your if and else statements. You could also speed your prime checker up quit a bit by building an constant array of known primes and checking against that first before you loop.

Comment: Why downvoted? He's pointed out a major problem in OP's code.